# Speed up PHP Imagick library PDF -> PNG conversion (20seconds !)

Tags: php, imagick

I am using [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.imagick.php) to convert the first page of a PDF to a PNG image. It is working, but it is very slow.

A conversion takes between 8 and 20 seconds for a ~100kb PDF.

Is there a way to speed up the conversion?

My code :

```
$im = new Imagick($url);
$im->setIteratorIndex(0);
$im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW);
$im->setCompressionQuality(90);
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->writeImage('C:/Shared/test.png');
```

Comment: `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` mismatches the output. You output PNG. Not that this has speed influence, but you might want to fix that in the first place.

Comment: Sure, but the conversion take still a lot of time

Comment: As written in the comment, changing that likely has *no* speed influence but you just might want to fix it because it's just not correct. If you don't want the user to wait, you can leave a message and redirect after 20 seconds and with sessions do the processing in the background (how this is done depends on PHP SAPI used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact , I don't need Imagick library to generate a simple JPG preview of the first page of a PDF, I just need GhostScript.

Command line conversion with GhostScript is always faster than Imagick (command line or through PHP)

Example with a 12 pages and 650kb :

- Command line GhostScript => 0.6 second
- Command line Imagick => 0.8 second
- PHP extension Imagick => 2.22 seconds

With some documents, Imagick takes 20 seconds against 1.5 second with direct GS command line.

Here is my test script

```
   <?php

    $pathToPdf = realpath("in.pdf");

    $pathToJpg = "./out.jpg";
    $pathToPng = "./out.png";

    try
        {

        $time_start = microtime(true);      
        $gsCall = "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.06\bin\gswin32.exe\" -q -dBATCH -dMaxBitmap=300000000 -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=jpeg -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=\"{0}\" \"{1}\" -c quit";
        $gsCall = str_replace(array('{0}', '{1}'), array($pathToJpg, $pathToPdf), $gsCall); // or use sprintf
        $str = exec($gsCall, $output=array(), $returnValue);
        echo $gsCall.'<br><br>';
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;        
        if($returnValue == 0)              
            print "<br><br>Conversion OK ".$time;
        else 
            print "<br><br>Conversion failed.<br />".var_dump($output);     

        $time_start = microtime(true);          
        exec('convert "'.$pathToPdf.'[0]" "'.$pathToPng.'"', $output, $returnValue);                        
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;
        if($returnValue == 0)              
            print "<br><br>Conversion OK ".$time;
        else 
            print "<br><br>Conversion failed.<br />".var_dump($output);

        $time_start = microtime(true);
        $im = new Imagick($pathToPdf);
        $im->setIteratorIndex(0);
        $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW);
        $im->setCompressionQuality(90);
        $im->setImageFormat("png");
        $im->writeImage('\\\\DELL-PC\Shared\test.png');
        //$im->thumbnailImage(200, 0);
        //echo $im;
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;
        print "<br><br>Conversion OK ".$time;
    }
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that this is likely due to ineficiencies on the Windows platform. On Linux, I benchmarked the 3 approaches (PHP Imagick, command line Imagick and ghostscript) and found that they take the same time.

Comment: I have discovered that it depends on the PDF to convert (with big images). But GhostScript is always stable instead of iMagick, but needs authorization to use Exec() command

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to speed up the convertion?

Sure, upgrade the machine with more processing power, more memory and a faster disk.

Also it looks like you're using a Windows operating system. I suggest you switch to a Linux system and compile the libraries optimized to the computer's architecture its running on.

Comment: Yep, most likely swapping to an OS that is native to what the developers of the tools use is always a good idea.

Comment: OK, there is no trick to speed up the conversion. Thanks for your comment

Comment: If those are no options for you, well how to make it faster? The code looks precise. Maybe invoking imagemagick on the commandline is faster than the PHP library (see `shell_exec`).

Comment: Well looks like that processor/memory/disk is the bottleneck here. Image processing is demanding. If you can not switch to optimized libraries on an optimized system, then there is not much you can do.

Comment: If fact, using GhostScript without Imagick permits to speed up the conversion. See my answer